# Glide library supports exif rotation

Tags: android, exif, picasso, android-glide

I'm searching a library for download process and caching of images with exif support.

The problem of [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) is that not support exif rotation.

My question is: [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library support exif rotation automatically?

Comment: try this library before uploading to the server, github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) gives support to exif rotation automatically.

Picasso will give support to exif rotation in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Please you can Android Universal Image Loader Library

Visit For Demo :https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader